# Message with Drop-Down/Combobox?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gui

Is there a way to include a drop-down or combo box in an Outlook message and have it display when you send the message to a recipient?  Whenever I create the Combo Box control, it seems to be hidden behind the message body and I can't bring it forward.

I am assuming I will have to place the combo Box outside of the message body, and then link a Label control to whichever value is selected so that it displays in the body.

I am also afraid that if I create a template with this drop-down, other users won't be able to use it because Outlook recognizes any Developer actions as a risk when the source is unknown - is there a way around this?

Comment: What do you need this combobox for?

Comment: @thims I am creating a template for our team to use, and the drop-down will include a list of values that are used repeatedly.  I could not think of an easier way and was not able to locate anything from other forums about how to easily implement this.

Answer (score 3):

So this isn't the solution that I expected, but it serves my purpose.  If you want a dropdown in Outlook within the body of an email template, simply create a ComboBox in Microsoft Word through the Developer tab:
[image: Developer tab ComboBox]

Then change the properties of your ComboBox to include the options that you want:

[image: ComboBox Properties]

Lastly, copy the entire ComboBox into a blank email message and save that as an OFT template.  This should keep the same dropdown options, and then can be used in the future whenever you create a message based on that template:

[image: ComboBox Email]

**Note:** I cannot determine how to use this method for Meeting Notices, as it seems to turn the ComboBox into plain text.  I will update with a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [CJK’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1027985/150988#1028522):

It may be impossible to successfully reopen a ComboBox-itized message template
if saved as an OFT file. 
It may work better if you save it as a msg file.